# tcp two sides trying to connect simultaneously

Tags: sockets, tcp

Consider the three way handshake of TCP. It is explained [here](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc793.html).

Now the article above mentions that two sides may try to connect simultaneously and the three way handshake works fine in this case.

Can we simulate this situation using the sockets api.
what we usually code using sockets is a passive open(server) and an active open(client)?

Comment: not exactly. an idea that cropped up in my mind during lectures. nothing for submission. just for learning.

Comment: fwiw, this is very similar to tcp hole punching.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is possible to cause a simultaneous TCP open using the sockets API. As Nikolai mentions, it is a matter of executing the following sequence with a timing such that the initial SYNs cross each other.

```
bind addr1, port1
connect addr2, port2
bind addr2, port2
connect addr1, port1
```

Here's how I achieved a simultaneous open using a single Linux host.

1. Slow down the loopback interface using [netem](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem)

   ```
   tc qdisc add dev lo root handle 1:0 netem delay 5sec
   ```
2. Run `netcat` twice

   ```
   netcat -p 3000 127.0.0.1 2000
   netcat -p 2000 127.0.0.1 3000
   ```

The two netcat processes connect to each other resulting in a single TCP connection

```
$ lsof -nP -c netcat -a -i # some columns removed 
COMMAND   PID NAME
netcat  27911 127.0.0.1:2000->127.0.0.1:3000 (ESTABLISHED)
netcat  27912 127.0.0.1:3000->127.0.0.1:2000 (ESTABLISHED)
```

Here's what tcpdump showed me (output edited for clarity)

```
127.0.0.1.2000 > 127.0.0.1.3000: Flags [S], seq 1139279069
127.0.0.1.3000 > 127.0.0.1.2000: Flags [S], seq 1170088782
127.0.0.1.3000 > 127.0.0.1.2000: Flags [S.], seq 1170088782, ack 1139279070
127.0.0.1.2000 > 127.0.0.1.3000: Flags [S.], seq 1139279069, ack 1170088783
```

Comment: that is a very comprehensive answer. i tried it and learnt new things. thank you

Comment: small correction. `tc qdisc replace` because on my pc it gives the error `RTNETLINK: file exists`. also i used the major and minor numbers from `ls -la /dev/loop0`.

Comment: i am seeing multiple SYN's being exchanged consecutively. all with the same sequence number. any reason.

Comment: you might try answering this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264154/when-is-the-push-flag-set-in-tcp-segment

Comment: @iamrohitbanga SYN's will get retransmitted until an ACK is received, which is why you see more than one with the same sequence number.  I saw them too, but chose not to include them here.

Answer (score 3):

For reference, and to provide an example in addition to the solid answers from sigjuice and Nikolai, simultaneous open can easily be achieved with python. In two different python interpreters, do:

```
>>> import socket
>>> s1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
>>> s1.bind(('localhost', 1111))
>>> s1.connect(('localhost', 2222))
>>> s1.send('hello')
5
>>> s1.recv(5)
'world'
```

and:

```
>>> import socket
>>> s2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
>>> s2.bind(('localhost', 2222))
>>> s2.connect(('localhost', 1111))
>>> s2.recv(5)
'hello'
>>> s2.send('world')
5
```

(the connect calls must come after both bind calls have returned)

Answer (score 2):

We do passive server and active client because it's easy to understand, [relatively] easy to implement, and easy to code for. Think of a store and a customer, we'd be in one of these situations:

- Customer goes to the store (active client), the store is open (passive server) - both are happy.

  Customer goes to the store, the store is closed (no server listening) - no luck for the customer.

  Store is open, no customers come - no luck for the store.

  Store is closed and no customers come - who a cares :)

Since the server passively waits for clients to connect it's easy to predict when a connection can take place. No pre-agreements (other then server address and port number) are necessary.

The *simultaneous open*, on the other hand, is subject to connect timeouts on both sides, i.e. this has to be carefully orchestrated for connection to take place so that `SYN`s cross "in-flight". It's an interesting artifact of the TCP protocol but I don't see any use for it in practice.

You can probably try simulating this by opening a socket, binding it to a port (so the other side knows where to connect to), and trying to connect. Both sides are symmetric. Can probably try that with netcat with `-p` option. You'd have to be pretty quick though :)

Comment: No, it's highly unlikely you'd be able to do that on a local host - the packets are just too fast :)

Comment: So executing symmetric connect()s on two hosts will establish a working TCP connection if the SYNs cross each other?  Is listen() not required at all in this scenario?

Comment: Yes, **listen()** is not required, **bind()** is.

Comment: There's a use case actually. To punch a TCP connection through two NATs.

Comment: Yes, an artificial solution to a kludgy hack on top of limited address space ... very practical :)