# How can you have a TCP connection back to the same port?

Tags: linux, networking, tcp

Machine is RHEL 5.3 (kernel 2.6.18).

Some times I notice in netstat that my application has connection, established TCP connection when *Local Address* and *Foreign Address* are same.

[Here](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1144254&tstart=180) same problem reported by someone else too.

The symptoms are same as described in link - client connects to port X port of server running locally. After some time netstat shows that client has connection from `127.0.0.1:X` to `127.0.0.1:X`

How it's possible?

**Edit 01**

Simultaneous open is causing the problem (thanks a lot to Hasturkun). You can see it on [classical TCP state diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Tcp_state_diagram.png) in transition from SYN_SENT state to SYNC_RECEIVED

Comment: The symptoms are same as described in link - client connects to port X port of server running locally. After some time netstat shows that client has connection from 127.0.0.1:X to 127.0.0.1:X

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This may be caused by TCP simultaneous connect (mentioned [on this post to LKML](http://lkml.org/lkml/2007/10/21/228), see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2231283/20270)).

It's possible for a program looping on trying to connect to a port within the dynamic local port range (which can be seen in `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range`),to succeed while the server is not listening on that port.

On a large enough number of attempts, the socket being used to connect may be bound to the same port being connected to, which succeeds due to previously mentioned simultaneous connect. You now magically have a client connected to itself

Comment: Indeed my client constantly tries to connect to server if server is down. So the question now how I can to prevent such situation? Does it means that server should use ports not in /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range range?

Comment: @dimba: yes, having the server listen to a port lower than the low end of that range will prevent this problem altogether

Comment: http://www.honeypots.net/misc/services defines port ranges. Do server should "Registered Port Numbers", while OS will allocate client port from "Dynamic Port Numbers" range (is it range defined by /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range?)?

Comment: @dimba: the range in `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range` is user settable, anything under the low value (`32768` in my case) will be safe against such an accidental connection. you do not _have_ to use one of the registered port numbers (especially if you aren't running the service registered on that port)

Answer (score 13):

A TCP connection is uniquely identified by this tuple `(local address, local port #, foreign address, foreign port #)`. There is no requirement that `local address` and `foreign address`, or even that the port numbers be different (though that would be exceedingly strange). But there is at most 1 TCP connection that has the same values for a given tuple.

When a computer connects to itself, it's local address and foreign address are almost always the same. After all, the 'local' side and 'foreign' side are actually the same computer. In fact, when this happens your computer should be showing two connections that have the same 'local' and 'foreign' addresses, but reversed port numbers.  For example:

```
$ ssh localhost
```

will result in two connections that look something like this:

```
$ netstat -nA inet | fgrep :22
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address        Foreign Address        State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:56039      127.0.0.1:22           ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:22         127.0.0.1:56039        ESTABLISHED
```

As you can see, the local address and foreign addresses are the same, but the port numbers are reversed. The unique tuple for this TCP connection is `(127.0.0.1, 56039, 127.0.0.1, 22)`. There will be no other TCP connection that has these same four fields.

The fact you see two is because your computer is both ends of the connection. Each end has its own view of which one is 'foreign' and which is 'local'.

You can even connect to yourself on the same port, and while this is not a common occurrence, it is not forbidden by the spec.  Here is a sample program in Python which will do this:

```
import socket
import time

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('127.0.0.1', 56443))
s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 56443))
time.sleep(30)
```

This code works because one way in which it's possible to open a TCP connection is to have the other side of the connection try to open one with you simultaneously. This is known as [simultaneous SYN exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231283/tcp-two-sides-trying-to-connect-simultaneously), and the linked to StackOverflow answer describes what that's about.

I also have a paper on [using simultaneous SYN exchange to get through NAT](http://www.omnifarious.org/~hopper/technical/tcp_splicing.html), though in that case the source and foreign would be completely different.

Comment: Understood. But how client eventually opens same port of server (see link in post)? The result server can not open it's server port as it already in use.

Comment: AFAIK, I do not connect intentionally from the same port to same port

Comment: @dimba - I have code now that shows how to make it happen. Why someone would do such a thing is another question. But it's certainly possible.

Comment: what is really odd is that one socket represents two ends, which probably requires very special treatment by OS. why do they find it necessary to go out of their way to support this use case?

Comment: @ZhongYu - because Linux. ☺️ Seriously, a good developer hears "that can never happen" and assumes it will. Once you realize the case exists there is no choice but to support it. Anything else would be incorrect behavior not conforming to the standard. Supporting this kind of edge case is what all software should do. It's the software engineering equivalent of making sure your bridge doesn't fall down when someone drives off the edge.