# TCP simultaneous open and self connect prevention

Tags: c++, networking, tcp

TCP standard has "simultaneous open" feature.

The implication of the feature, client trying to connect to local port, when the port is from [ephemeral range](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftpd/doc/misc/ephemeral_ports.html), can occasionally connect to itself (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949858/how-can-you-have-a-tcp-connection-back-to-the-same-port)).

So client think it's connected to server, while it actually connected to itself. From other side, server can not open its server port, since it's occupied/stolen by client.

I'm using RHEL 5.3 and my clients constantly tries to connect to local server. 
Eventually client connects to itself.

I want to prevent the situation. I see two possible solutions to the problem:

1. Don't use ephemeral ports for server ports. 
   Agree ephemeral port range and configure it on your machines (see [ephemeral range](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftpd/doc/misc/ephemeral_ports.html))
2. Check *connect()* as somebody propose [here](http://www.webservertalk.com/archive65-2004-3-161913.html).

What do you thinks?
How do you handle the issue?

**P.S. 1**

Except of the solution, which I obviously looking for, 
I'd like you to share your real life experience with the problem.

When I found the cause of the problem, I was "astonished" on my work place people are not familiar with it. Polling server by connecting it periodically is IMHO common practice, 
so how it's that the problem is not commonly known.

Comment: I think the question needs to be clarified. Here is my understanding of it:
 - You have a server running on a (non-reserved) port that is in the ephemeral range. For example, port 56789.
 - A client on the local machine polls the server by connecting to 'localhost:56789'.
 - If the server is down, it is possible that the outbound port is chosen to be 56789 as well.

Am I understanding correctly?
What is the result of the connect call in this case?

Comment: You understand it correctly. I've edited the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For server you need to bind() socket to port. Once addr:port pair had socket bound, it will no longer be used for implicit binding in connect().

No problem, no trouble.

Comment: The problem is when local server is down. Then client polling server by performing connect periodically each several seconds. OS pick up source port (a.k.a. ephemeral port). If server port is from ephemeral port range, than I connect to myself.

Comment: So just do bind() before connect() and check if assigned ephemeral port equals to expected server port. If not, do connect().

Comment: bind() before connnect() only works if there is only one port number that's causing the trouble. If the client & server are connecting on multiple ports, then these ports can end up being connected to each other in the client if the server isn't running. bind() would then need to check against each of the port numbers in use, which is a bit of a pain if you want to keep areas of the code isolated.

Answer (score 15):

When I stumbled into this I was flabbergasted. I could figure out that the outgoing
port number accidentally matches the incoming port number, but not why the TCP
handshake (SYN SYN-ACK ACK) would succeed (ask yourself: who is sending the ACK if
there is nobody doing a listen() and accept()???)

Both Linux and FreeBSD show this behavior.

Anyway, one solution is to stay out of the high range of port numbers for servers.

I noticed that Darwin side-steps this issue by not allowing the outgoing port
to be the same as the destination port. They must have been bitten by this as well...

An easy way to show this effect is as follows:

```
while true
do
    telnet 127.0.0.1 50000 
done
```

And wait for a minute or so and you will be chatting with yourself...

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
hello?
hello?
```

Anyway, it makes good job interview material.

Comment: @Marchel Love your example with telnet

Comment: "Anyway, it makes good job interview material." - you wouldn't have hired me until today then :)

Comment: Take a look at a TCP state transition diagram. There is an active open, the connection sends a SYN and goes into the SYN_SENT state, then gets that SYN and sends a SYN + ACK and goes into SYN_RCVD. http://ssfnet.org/Exchange/tcp/tcpTutorialNotes.html#ST

Answer (score 3):

Bind the client socket to port 0 (system assigns), check the system assigned port, if it matches the local server port you already know the server is down and and can skip connect().

Comment: This doesn't work in my case, since I have several local servers I'm trying to connect to. Even if the bind shows a different port, since another thread is also trying to connect those two threads can end up connected to each other - rather than the local server (which isn't up yet). It's a rare case, but it happens.

Answer (score 1):

Note that this solution is theoretical and I have not tested it on my own. I've not experienced it before (or did not realize) and hopefully I won't experience it anymore.

I'm assuming that you cannot edit neither the client source code nor the server source. Additionally I'm assuming the real problem is the server which cannot start.

Launch the server with a starter application. If the target port that the server will bind is being used by any process, create an RST (reset packet) by using raw sockets.

The post below briefly describes what an RST packet is (taken from http://forum.soft32.com/linux/killing-socket-connection-cmdline-ftopict473059.html)

> You have to look at a "raw socket" packet generator. 
>   And you have to be superuser. 
>   You probably need a network sniffer as well.
>
> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_socket 
>   http://kerneltrap.org/node/3072 - TCP RST attacks 
>   http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-RawIP/lib/Net/RawIP.pm - a Perl module 
>   http://mixter.void.ru/rawip.html - raw IP in C
>
> In the C version, you want a TH_RST packet.
>
> RST is designed to handle the following case.
>
> A and B establish a connection. 
>   B reboots, and forgets about this. 
>   A sends a packet to B to port X from port Y.
>
> B sends a RST packet back, saying "what are you talking about? I don't 
>   have a connection with you. Please close this connection down."
>
> So you have to know/fake the IP address of B, and know both ports X 
>   and Y. One of the ports will be the well known port number. The other 
>   you have to find out. I thnk you also need to know the sequence 
>   number.
>
> Typically people do this with a sniffer. You could use a switch with a 
>   packet mirroring function, or run a sniffer on either host A or B.
>
> As a note, Comcast did this to disable P2P traffic. 
>   http://www.eff.org/wp/packet-forgery-isps-report-comcast-affair

In our case we don't need to use a sniffer since we know the information below:

> So you have to know/fake the IP address of B, and know both ports X 
>   and Y

X = Y and B's IP address is localhost

Tutorial on http://mixter.void.ru/rawip.html describes how to use Raw Sockets.

**NOTE** that any other process on the system might also steal our target port from ephemeral pool. (e.g. Mozilla Firefox) This solution will not work on this type of connections since X != Y B's IP address is not localhost but something like 192.168.1.43 on eth0. In this case you might use netstat to retrieve X, Y and B's IP address and then create a RST packet accordingly.

Comment: -1: You're trying to solve a problem that is only vaguely related to the OP's stated issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, that is an odd problem.  If you have a client / server on the same machine and it will always be on the same machine perhaps shared memory or a Unix domain socket or some other form of IPC is a better choice.

Other options would be to run the server on a fixed port and the client on a fixed source port.  Say, the server runs on 5000 and the client runs on 5001.  You do have the issue of binding to either of these if something else is bound to them.

You could run the server on an even port number and force the client to an odd port number.  Pick a random number in the ephemeral range, OR it with 1, and then call bind() with that.  If bind() fails with EADDRINUSE then pick a different odd port number and try again.

Answer (score 0):

That's an interesting issue! If you're mostly concerned that your server is running, you could always implement a heartbeat mechanism in the server itself to report status to another process. Or you could write a script to check and see if your server process is running.

If you're concerned more about the actual connection to the server being available, I'd suggest moving your client to a different machine. This way you can verify that your server at least has some network connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this is a bug in the TCP spec; listening sockets shouldn't be able to send unsolicited SYNs, and receiving a SYN (rather than a SYN+ACK) after you've sent one should be illegal and result in a reset, which would quickly let the client close the unluckily-chosen local port. But nobody asked for my opinion ;)

As you say, the obvious answer is not to listen in the ephemeral port range. Another solution, if you **know** you'll be connecting to a local machine, is to design your protocol so that the server sends the first message, and have a short timeout on the client side for receiving that message.

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem you are having seems to be that while the server is down, something else can use the ephemeral port you expect for your server as the source port for an outgoing connection. The detail of how that happens is separate to the actual problem, and it can happen in ways other than the way you describe.

The solution to that problem is to set SO_REUSEADDR on the socket. That will let you create a server on a port that has a current outgoing connection.

If you really care about that port number, you can use operating specific methods to stop it being allocated as an ephemeral port.

Answer (score -1):

This option isn't actually implemented in most TCPs. Do you have an *actual* problem?

Comment: I have the problem, since my clients constantly trying to connect each several seconds to local server. I'm using Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5.3 based on kernel 2.6.18 and it does implement simultaneous open.