# Why isn't an accept()-like socket function available that doesn't create a new file descriptor?

Tags: c, sockets, networking

accept() is defined to always create another file descriptor to accept new connections from the client, but if it is known beforehand that we are only going to be accepting one client and one connection, why bother with creating a new file descriptor? Are there any descriptions of why this is the case in any defined standards?

Comment: Probably because the interface was designed with the idea that you'd be attempting to communicate with multiple clients from a server, and that the case of 1 max client is not common enough to special-case. tl;dr version: your use case is not special enough to warrant consideration in API, so program against the API provided.

Comment: Consider all the work going on in the kernel / networking stack; the 'overhead' of returning a file descriptor value is negligible. There's no point adding complexity to the general solution provided by `accept()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TCP protocol described in [RFC 793](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc793.txt) describes the terms *socket* and *connection*. A *socket* is an IP address and port number pair. A *connection* is a pair of *sockets*. In this sense, the same *socket* can be used for multiple *connections*. It is in this sense that the `socket` being passed to `accept()` is being used. Since a *socket* can be used for multiple connections, and the `socket` passed to `accept()` represents that *socket*, the API creates a new `socket` to represent the *connection*.

If you just want an easy way to make sure the one `socket` that `accept()` creates for you is the same socket you used to do the `accept()` call on, then use a wrapper FTW:

```
int accept_one (int accept_sock, struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t *addrlen) {
    int sock = accept(accept_sock, addr, addrlen);
    if (sock >= 0) {
        dup2(sock, accept_sock);
        close(sock);
        sock = accept_sock;
    }
    return sock;
}
```

If you are wanting  a way for a client and server to connect to each other, without creating any more than just one `socket` on each side, such an API does exist. The API is `connect()`, and it succeeds when you achieve a [*simultaneous open*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139808/tcp-simultaneous-open-and-self-connect-prevention).

```
static struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
static struct sockaddr_in client_addr;

void init_addr (struct sockaddr_in *addr, short port) {
    struct sockaddr_in tmp = {
        .sin_family = AF_INET, .sin_port = htons(port),
        .sin_addr = { htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK) } };
    *addr = tmp;
}

void connect_accept (int sock,
                     struct sockaddr_in *from, struct sockaddr_in *to) {
    const int one = 1;
    int r;
    setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &one, sizeof(one));
    bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)from, sizeof(*from));
    do r = connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)to, sizeof(*to)); while (r != 0);
}

void do_peer (char *who, const char *msg, size_t len,
              struct sockaddr_in *from, struct sockaddr_in *to) {
    int sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    connect_accept(sock, from, to);
    write(sock, msg, len-1);
    shutdown(sock, SHUT_WR);
    char buf[256];
    int r = read(sock, buf, sizeof(buf));
    close(sock);
    if (r > 0) printf("%s received: %.*s%s", who, r, buf,
                      buf[r-1] == '\n' ? "" : "...\n");
    else if (r < 0) perror("read");
}

void do_client () {
    const char msg[] = "client says hi\n";
    do_peer("client", msg, sizeof(msg), &client_addr, &server_addr);
}

void do_server () {
    const char msg[] = "server says hi\n";
    do_peer("server", msg, sizeof(msg), &server_addr, &client_addr);
}

int main () {
    init_addr(&server_addr, 4321);
    init_addr(&client_addr, 4322);
    pid_t p = fork();
    switch (p) {
    case 0:  do_client(); break;
    case -1: perror("fork"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    default: do_server(); waitpid(p, 0, 0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If instead you are worried about performance issues, I believe those worries are misguided. Using the TCP protocol, you already have to wait at least one full round trip on the network between the client and the server, so the extra overhead of dealing with another socket is negligible. A possible case where you might care about that overhead is if the client and server are on the same machine, but even then, it is only an issue if the connections are very short lived. If the connections are so short lived, then it would probably be better to redesign your solution to either use a cheaper communication medium (e.g., shared memory), or apply framing on your data and use a persistent connection.

Comment: This was the answer I was hoping for. Very informative. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

When designing APIs I think there is value in being generic.  Why have 2 APIs, one for accepting potentially multiple connections and one for using fewer file descriptors?  The latter case doesn't seem high priority enough to justify an entirely new syscall when the API we have today will do and you can use it to implement the behavior you want just fine.

On the other hand, Windows has [`AcceptEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737524(v=vs.85).aspx) which lets you re-use previous socket handles that previously represented otherwise unrelated, previously connected sockets.  I believe this is to avoid the performance hit of entering the kernel again to close sockets after they are disconnected.  Not exactly what you are describing but vaguely similar.  (Though meant to scale up rather than scale down.)

**Update:** One month later I think it's a little strange that you created a bounty on this.  I think the answer is clear - the current interfaces can do what you ask for just fine and there's really no motivation to add, let alone standardize, a new interface for your fringe case.  With the current interfaces you can `close` the original socket after `accept` succeeds and it won't harm anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Because it isn't required. If you only have one client, you only do the operation once; you have plenty of file descriptors to spare; and compared to network overheads the 'overhead' is vanishingly small. The case that you would want to 'optimize' as an API designer is when you have thousands of clients.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that changes between the socket returned by listen and the socket descriptor returned by accept, is that the new socket is in the ESTABILISHED state instead of the LISTEN state.So you can re-use the socket created after invoking the listen functions to accept other connections.

Answer (score 0):

As accept() is designed to accept new client .

it required three things, general socket descriptor which must bind to a specific port number  for serving at that port number and a structure to store the client information and another int value to store size of client .

it return a new_socket_descriptor for serving the particular client which is accepted by server.

the first parameter is a socket descriptor used to accept client.And for concurrence server, it is always use for accepting client connection .So it should  not modify by any accept() call.

so new socket descriptor returned by accept() to serve new connected client.

the server socket descriptor(1st parameter) bind to server property.server property always designed to a fixed type that is its port number ,type of connection,protocol family all are fixed.So same file descriptor is used again and again.

Another point is that these property are used to filter client connection which are made for that particular server.

For clients,information for each client different minimum ip address used by every client unique and these property are bind to new file descriptor so always a new file descriptor returned by accept() function success.

NOTE:-

that is you require one file descriptor must for client accepting and depending upon maximum number of client you want to accept/serve use that much file descriptor for serving clients.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that your specific example of exactly one connection **is** handled in the current API and was designed into the API's use cases from the start. The explanation for how the single socket case is handled lies in the way socket programs were designed to work when the BSD socket interface was first invented.

The socket API was designed to *always* be able to accept connections. The fundamental principle is that when a connection arrives, the program should have the final decision as to whether the connection is accepted or not. However, the application must also never miss a connection while making this decision. Thus, the API was designed only to be parallel and `accept()` was specified to return a different socket from `listen()`, so that `listen()` could continue listening for further connection requests while the application made its decision about the connection request just received. This was a fundamental design decision and is not documented anywhere; it was just assumed that socket programs would have to work that way in order to be useful.

In the old days before threads were invented, the parallelism required to implement socket servers on Unix-like systems relied on `fork()`. A new connection was accepted, the program would split itself into two identical copies using `fork()`, and then one copy would handle the new connection while the original copy continued listening for incoming connection attempts. In the `fork()` model, even though `accept()` returns a new file handle, the use case of handling exactly one connection was supported and was achieved by just letting the "listening" copy of the program exit while the second "accept" copy handles the single connection.

The following pseudo code shows this:

```
fd = socket();

listen(fd, 1);  /* allow 1 unanswered connection in the backlog */

switch (fork())
{
    case  0: break;     /* child process; handle connection */
    case -1: exit (1);  /* error. exit anyway. */
    default: exit (0);  /* parent process; exit as only one connection needed */
}

/* if we get here our single connection can be accepted and handled.
 */
accept_fd = accept(fd);
```

This programming paradigm meant that whether servers accepted a single connection, or stayed in loops handling multiple connections, the code was virtually identical in both cases. Nowadays we have threads instead of `fork()`. However, as the *paradigm* still remains to this today, it has never been necessary to change or upgrade the socket API.