# Can one reliably connect a TCP socket to itself?

Tags: sockets, tcp

I am wondering whether it is possible to reliably connect a TCP socket to itself -- that is, to get just one socket where whatever you send() on you receive back through recv(). I saw that this can happen (e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17584383/why-can-a-socket-connect-to-its-own-ephemeral-port), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139808/tcp-simultaneous-open-and-self-connect-prevention), and [here](http://sgros.blogspot.co.uk/2013/08/tcp-client-self-connect.html)), but none of these posts explain how to do this programmatically and reliably (i.e., this is usually touted as a curiosity, rather than a feature one would use deliberately). I'm interested in a solution for Windows, Mac, and Linux.

Just for completeness, please let me explain why I'm interested in this. I'm writing a cloud-based application where servers can send messages to other servers, including themselves. Each server uses one socket to talk to other servers, and so, to unify the code and make certain threading issues simpler, it would be good if the server could talk to itself using just one socket as well.

**EDIT:** @Rufflewind suggested connecting to the loopback adapter. I tried that using the code below, both with and without the call to listen. In all cases, however, I got an error (either "Invalid argument" or "Operation not supported"). What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

void die(const char* const message) {
    perror(message);
    exit(0);
}

#define CHECK(operation,message) \
    if ((operation) != 0) \
        die(message)

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    sockaddr_in local;
    local.sin_family = AF_INET;
    local.sin_port = htons(40000);
    inet_aton("127.0.0.1", &local.sin_addr);
    int sck = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    CHECK(bind(sck, (struct sockaddr *)&local, sizeof(local)), "Error while binding the socket to an address");
//    CHECK(listen(sck, 1), "Error while listening.");
    CHECK(connect(sck, (struct sockaddr *)&local, sizeof(local)), "Error while connecting the socket to self");
    std::cout << "Succeeded in connecting sockets!" << std::endl;
    const char* message = "ABCDEFGH";
    const size_t messageLength = ::strlen(message) + 1;
    const char* currentSend = message;
    ssize_t leftToSend = messageLength;
    while (leftToSend != 0) {
        const ssize_t sent = send(sck, currentSend, leftToSend, 0);
        if (sent == -1)
            die("Can't send.");
        currentSend += sent;
        leftToSend -= sent;
    }
    std::cout << "Sent the message!" << std::endl;
    char buffer[256];
    char* currentRead = buffer;
    size_t leftToRead = messageLength;
    while (leftToRead != 0) {
        const ssize_t read = recv(sck, currentRead, leftToRead, 0);
        if (read == -1)
            die("Can't read.");
        currentRead += read;
        leftToRead -= read;
    }
    std::cout << "Received message: " << buffer << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You mean, like, connecting to an echo server?

Comment: @MartinJames I thought of this: http://thecodelesscode.com/case/28

Comment: Yes, something like that, although it would be better if there are no external processes involved (i.e., you don't need to run a real echo server in a separate thread - ideally it would all be dealt with by the TCP stack since the socket would have the same outgoing and incoming addresses).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward approach would be to bind to the loopback adapter.  Just listen to `127.0.0.1` on some arbitrary port and the connect to that.

The problem with this approach is that the port is global on the machine, so that means *other* programs can connect to it too, and if you have multiple programs you might run into conflicts or conceivably exhaust all the possible ports.

Another approach is to use Unix domain sockets, but this is not supported on Windows.

Comment: Thank you. I've updated my post with some sample code in which I tried that, but it didn't work. I would be very thankful if you could point out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Also, please note that I was hoping I could have just **one** socket that does all the looping "by itself" -- that is, without someone having to read the data and then write it back. If worst comes to worst, I guess I can always have a separate loopback thread; however, I was just hoping I could have a "self-looping socket" provided by the system.

Comment: Your code seems to work just fine on my machine (Linux).

Comment: Hmm, now I tried on Linux and it works indeed. Originally I was using Mac OS X and there it doesn't work. So it seems that there is no portable way to achieve this on all platforms I'm interested in. Anyway, thank you for your help!

Comment: The way you connect to loopback is a bit unconventional.  As you said, the most portable approach requires a second thread to act as a client that does the echoing.

Comment: Yes, I was aware of that, but I hoped I could avoid the complications. Thanks again for your help!