# C++: client connects without server

Tags: c++, sockets, networking

I am trying to make a C++ server-client communication program. Currently, both server and client are on localhost.

When I run server.cpp, it waits at "Listening...", as expected, and does not continue further till I don't run client.cpp. When client is run, server prints "Connected" and both server and client end.

But when I run client.cpp *only*, it prints "Connecting..." and then "Connected" after one second, even if server.cpp is not running, and specified port is not open.

I have triple checked both codes, tried them many times, also checked open ports before running *only* client, changed port many times, but nothing worked. Why does client say "Connected" even when server is not running?

**server.cpp:**

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define PORT 11056

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, PF_UNSPEC);
    if (sock == -1) {
        printf("E) Socket creation\n");
        return 1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in server, client;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = PORT;
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;

    int binded = bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server));
    if (binded == -1) {
        printf("E) Binding\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("4) Listening...\n");
    listen(sock, 5);

    int new_sock = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t *)sizeof(client));
    printf("5) Connected\n");

    shutdown(sock, SHUT_RDWR);
    close(new_sock);
    close(sock);

    printf("EXIT\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**client.cpp**

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define PORT 11056

int main(int argc, char** argv) {  
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, PF_UNSPEC);
    if(sock == -1) {
        printf("Error creating socket\n");
        return 1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in client;
    client.sin_port = PORT;
    client.sin_family = AF_INET;
    client.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    printf("3) Connecting...\n");
    connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&client, sizeof(client));
    printf("4) Connected\n");

    close(sock);

    printf("EXIT");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The socket can connect to itself.  port 11056 is a port that can be assigned to your client socket when it is created and then you attempt to connect to your own socket.  http://sgros.blogspot.com/2013/08/tcp-client-self-connect.html  You can google on tcp client self connect and get a bunch more results.

Comment: Will the code work well if I make server and client on different machines?

Comment: Yes, or just make sure to start the server before you start the client if they are on the same machine.

Comment: Yep, when I ran server first and client later (with server running), I got expected results. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TCP simultaneous open and self connect prevention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139808/tcp-simultaneous-open-and-self-connect-prevention)

Comment: Whatif I bind the client to a port other than 11056?

Comment: if you connect to a port that could be used for your client socket, there is always the possibility of this happening.   It might be more or less likely if you change the number, but if it's something the OS might use for your client socket, it can still happen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148567/discussion-between-deepesh-choudhary-and-xaxxon).

Comment: is the client really connecting? check the return value to know if it is really connecting as you thought

Comment: @dlmeetei Thanks! I got it, when I run only client, it returns -1, errno set to "ECONNREFUSED", and when I run it after running the server, I get no error. Problem solved!

Comment: @dlmeetei i was so excited that I saw what I thought was the same problem as something I spent a while on a week ago that I didn't even see that he didn't have the connect in a loop...  good catch.  A TCP client socket can do a full handshake with itself, though, in the right situatino.. which still kinda boggles my mind.