# Can two ends of a TCP connection have the same IP and port?

Tags: networking, tcp

A TCP connection is uniquely identified by { local_IP, local_port, remote_IP, remote_port }.

Is it possible that `local_IP==remote_IP` and `local_port==remote_port`?

Comment: apparently a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949858/how-can-you-have-a-tcp-connection-back-to-the-same-port?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question...

It is possible and observed, see [How can you have a TCP connection back to the same port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949858/how-can-you-have-a-tcp-connection-back-to-the-same-port)