# POSIX socket client connecting to itself

Tags: c++, sockets, client, centos7, vmware-workstation

I'm getting very strange behavior with my TCP client socket code, so I wrote up a simple test program.

The code below is meant to constantly retry connecting to a server (`127.0.0.1:36000`) until it connects. It is being compiled with `g++ 4.8.5` with `-std=c++98` (C++03/11 cannot be used).

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <cctype>
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int sd = -1;

    while (true)
    {
        close(sd);

        std::cout << "trying to connect" << std::endl;

        if ((sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
        {
            std::cerr << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
            continue;
        }

        std::cout << "socket created " << sd << std::endl;

        struct sockaddr_in addr;
        memset((char *)&addr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
        addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

        if (!inet_aton("127.0.0.1", &addr.sin_addr))
        {
            std::cerr << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
            continue;
        }
        std::cout << "translated ip" << std::endl;

        addr.sin_port = htons(36000);

        if (connect(sd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) < 0)
        {
            std::cerr << "Error connecting socket" << std::endl;
            continue;
        }

        std::cout << "connected " << inet_ntoa(addr.sin_addr) << ":" << ntohs(addr.sin_port) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "write " << write(sd, "from client", 11) << std::endl;

        char buf[1024] = {0};
        int size;
        while ((size = read(sd, buf, 1024, 0, NULL, NULL)) > -1)
        {
            buf[size] = 0;
            std::cout << "received " << size << " ["  << buf << "]" << std::endl;
        }

        std::cout << "stopped" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Despite the fact that there is no server or any other program using port 36000, the `connect` call succeeds, as will the `write`. I'm getting output that looks like:

```
trying to connect
socket created 3
translated ip
Error connecting socket
trying to connect
socket created 3
translated ip
Error connecting socket
...
...
...
trying to connect
socket created 3
translated ip
connected 127.0.0.1:36000
write 11
received 11 [from client]
```

If the port is changed to any other unused port (35999, 36001, etc), `connect` will only fail (connection refused). Other ports never seem to connect.

The arguments `recvfrom` are not modified if they are present.

Additionally, it only happens when the socket is not timing out. If the socket is still timing out, `connect` will fail.

Running `netstat -an` while the `read` is blocked will return

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:36000         127.0.0.1:36000         ESTABLISHED
```

This happens on CentOS 6.7 and 7 vms.

What is happening? Is there something strange about port `36000`? Is this a Centos/`connect` bug? Am I doing something silly?

This is a partial duplicate of [How can you have a TCP connection back to the same port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949858/how-can-you-have-a-tcp-connection-back-to-the-same-port/4950218#4950218) but that still doesn't explain why it is only happening on port 36000.

Comment: what data are you receiving back?   If you send more do you receive more?  is it always the same data you receive back?   How do you know nothing is running on that port?  what happens if you run netstat -an
 while it's connected?  (put a pause in there of some sort after you connect so you can run netstat)

Comment: also, how many attempts is the ... in your sample output?  that number may be interesting.  is it consistent?

Comment: The data I'm getting back is always the string `from client`. I know nothing is on port 36000 because there should be nothing on it, and netstat does not show anything on 36000 when the code is not running. While the second `read` is blocked, netstat will show `127.0.0.1:36000` for source and destination.

Comment: The number of loops run before the connection is established seems to be random.

Comment: I'm grasping at straws, but since you're already calling recvfrom (which is abnormal for a TCP connection... usually you'd just use read, since you already know the remote address, since you connected to it), capture and print the sockaddr data in the 5th (and 6th) parameters

Comment: The same thing happens if `read` is used. Besides, `read` should not be affecting `connect`

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that recvfrom was causing the problem, just giving you a tidbit of tangential info.   What data do you get from the sockaddr_in if you pass it into your recvfrom call?

Comment: It's also possible this is some sort of DOS protection mechanism?   I couldn't find anything with a quick google, though.  But you're sort of basically DOSing yourself.

Comment: I don't think its triggering a DOS protection mechanism. `connect` blocks on any other port I try.

Comment: have you tried rebooting?  I'm sort of being silly, but ... still.  have you tried it?

Comment: Yes. The same thing still happens.

Comment: do you have anything in your /etc/inet.d xinet.d whateverinet.d?  does that stuff even still exist?   .. for port 36000?  it doesn't seem to be a standard port for anything that I could find, but maybe something on your computer?   Also, what if you just make a loop in bash calling nc?   Can you reproduce the connection that way?

Comment: Nope. Nothing in `/etc/*`. I got `nc -p 36000 localhost 36000` to reproduce this, but that doesn't explain why the syscalls are focusing on port 36000

Comment: the -p option to nc isn't the same as what you're doing.  That's the equivalent of a bind() call, I believe.  You're socket is being assigned an ephemeral port... hrmm.  What stops the ephemeral port from....

Comment: none of my theories explain why you can only reproduce this on port 36000 at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I execute your program with tcpdump running I get some interesting output.

```
sudo tcpdump -i lo

...
14:51:16.477170 IP localhost.35988 > localhost.36000: Flags [S], seq 3826079620, win 65495, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 95720198 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
14:51:16.477173 IP localhost.36000 > localhost.35988: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 3826079621, win 0, length 0
14:51:16.477203 IP localhost.35990 > localhost.36000: Flags [S], seq 2431563950, win 65495, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 95720198 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
14:51:16.477206 IP localhost.36000 > localhost.35990: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 2431563951, win 0, length 0
14:51:16.477247 IP localhost.35992 > localhost.36000: Flags [S], seq 3688613148, win 65495, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 95720198 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
14:51:16.477250 IP localhost.36000 > localhost.35992: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 3688613149, win 0, length 0
14:51:16.477282 IP localhost.35994 > localhost.36000: Flags [S], seq 1503921089, win 65495, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 95720198 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
14:51:16.477285 IP localhost.36000 > localhost.35994: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 1503921090, win 0, length 0
14:51:16.477315 IP localhost.35996 > localhost.36000: Flags [S], seq 2868111150, win 65495, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 95720198 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
14:51:16.477318 IP localhost.36000 > localhost.35996: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 2868111151, win 0, length 0
14:51:16.477348 IP localhost.35998 > localhost.36000: Flags [S], seq 281293569, win 65495, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 95720198 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
14:51:16.477351 IP localhost.36000 > localhost.35998: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 281293570, win 0, length 0
14:51:16.477381 IP localhost.36000 > localhost.36000: Flags [S], seq 3196081163, win 65495, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 95720198 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
14:51:16.477386 IP localhost.36000 > localhost.36000: Flags [S.], seq 3196081163, ack 3196081164, win 65495, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 95720198 ecr 95720198,nop,wscale 7], length 0
14:51:16.477422 IP localhost.36000 > localhost.36000: Flags [.], ack 1, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 95720198 ecr 95720198], length 0
```

This output shows that the socket is actually performing the TCP 3-way handshake with itself.  For some reason (in at least CentOS 6.7) It appears to be incrementing the source port by 2 thus preventing the issue on port 35999, 36001.

In [RFC 793](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793#section-3.4) it talks about this type of connection as a simultaneous connection.